# View data restriction on spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Usually, If many members have access to a google-sheet, they all can edit/view that data provided everyone has read-write access.

But we want to restrict users to view and edit only their own data in that spreadsheet and only admin can have access to the data entered by all users using google apps script(gas). Is it possible?

I have gone through Google Apps Script Documentation but didn't find anything related to this matter.

Comment: You cannot restrict viewing of sheets to specific users. Sheets are either hidden or visible. You could have several spreadsheets, one for each user, then [import](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) their data into a summary spreadsheet so admin can see all users' data.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to give everyone personal spreadsheet (file) and then have one master spreadsheet which will be compiled with data of slave spreadsheets using **`IMPORTRANGE()`** formula.